# Equality of estimates is almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $θ^∗_1(X)$ and $θ^∗_2(X)$ be the two best estimates ​​in the root-mean-square approach to estimating the parameter $θ$ in the class of all estimates with the same mathematical expectation $τ(θ)$. I need to prove that then for $\forall θ$ $θ^∗_1(X)$ and $θ^∗_2(X)$ coincide almost surely. By the "$θ^∗_1(X)$ is the best estimate ​​in the root-mean-square approach in the class of all estimates with the same mathematical expectation $τ(θ)$" I mean that the following inequality holds:
$$
E(θ^∗_1(X) - θ)^2 \leq E(\overline{θ}(X) - θ)^2
$$
$\forall$ estimate $\overline{θ}(X)$ from the class of all estimates with the same mathematical expectation $τ(θ)$.
I don’t understand how to solve this problem, because I don’t understand how to connect the mathematical expectation of a random variable with a random variable, for example, using an inequality. I would be gratefull for any hint, thank you.

Comment: I am not sure I understand "the" in "the two best estimates".  Are  $θ^∗_1(X)$ and $θ^∗_2(X)$ both "best estimates" or is one "best" and the other "second best" (whatever that might mean)?

Comment: I suspect you will want to show $E[(θ^∗_1(X) - θ^∗_2(X))^2]=0$

Comment: @Henry both of estimates are best, it means that following inequalities holds: $E(θ^∗_1(X) - θ)^2 \leq E(θ^*_2(X) - θ)^2$ and $E(θ^∗_2(X) - θ)^2 \leq E(θ^*_1(X) - θ)^2$

Comment: @Henry I want to show that $Pr(θ^∗_1(X)=θ^∗_2(X)) = 1$ i.e. they are equal almost surely

Comment: So you have $E[(θ^∗_1(X) - θ)^2] = E[(θ^*_2(X) - θ)^2]$.  Can you use this to show     $E[(θ^∗_1(X) - θ^∗_2(X))^2]=0$?

Comment: @Henry i've got problems, i just understand that $E\theta_1^2 = E\theta_2^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\zeta, \eta$ be two best estimators in the same expectation class. Then since we know that $$ \mathbb{E}_\theta[(\zeta - \theta)^2] \le \mathbb{E}_\theta[(\eta - \theta)^2] \iff \mathbb{E}[ (\zeta - \eta)(\zeta + \eta - 2\theta)] \le 0,$$ and by exchanging $\zeta, \eta$, that $\mathbb{E}_\theta[(\zeta - \eta)(\zeta + \eta - 2\theta)] \ge 0,$ we have that $$ 0 = \mathbb{E}_\theta[(\zeta - \eta)(\zeta + \eta - 2\theta)] = \mathbb{E}_\theta[\zeta^2 - \eta^2] - 2\theta \mathbb{E}_\theta[\zeta -\eta]\\ \iff \mathbb{E}_\theta[\zeta^2] = \mathbb{E}_\theta[\eta^2].$$

Further, note that if $\zeta, \eta$ are both best estimators, so is any convex combination of them. Indeed, for $\alpha \in (0,1),$ we have that for $\phi = \alpha \zeta + (1-\alpha)\eta$, clearly the mean of $\phi$ is the same as that of $\zeta$ and $\eta,$ and we further have $$ \mathbb{E}_\theta[ (\phi - \theta)^2] = \alpha^2 \mathbb{E}_\theta[(\zeta - \theta)^2] + (1-\alpha)^2\mathbb{E}_\theta[ (\eta - \theta)^2] + 2\alpha(1-\alpha) \mathbb{E}_\theta[(\zeta - \theta)(\eta - \theta)]\\ \le \alpha^2 \mathbb{E}_\theta[(\zeta - \theta)^2] + (1-\alpha)^2\mathbb{E}_\theta[ (\eta - \theta)^2] + 2\alpha(1-\alpha) \sqrt{\mathbb{E}_\theta[(\zeta - \theta)^2] \mathbb{E}_\theta[(\eta - \theta)^2]}\\ = \left(\alpha \sqrt{\mathbb{E}_\theta[(\zeta - \theta)^2]} + (1-\alpha) \sqrt{\mathbb{E}_\theta[(\eta - \theta)^2]} \right)^{2} = \mathbb{E}_\theta[(\zeta - \theta)^2],$$ where the inequality is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Now plugging in $\zeta = \theta_1, \eta = \theta_2$, we know that $$ \mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta_1^2] = \mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta_2^2],$$ and plugging in $\zeta = \theta_1, \eta = (\theta_1 + \theta_2)/2,$ we know that $$ \mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta_1^2] = \mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta_1^2/4] +  \mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta_2^2/4] +  \mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta_1\theta_2/2] \iff \mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta_1^2] = \mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta_1\theta_2].$$ But then observe that $$ \mathbb{E}_\theta[ (\theta_1 - \theta_2)^2] = \mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta_1^2] + \mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta_2]^2 - 2\mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta_1\theta_2] = 0.$$ Since $(\theta_1 - \theta_2)^2 \ge 0$ surely, this can occur iff no matter the $\theta,$ it holds that $$ P_\theta( (\theta_1 - \theta_2)^2 > 0) = 0 \iff P_\theta( \theta_1 = \theta_2) = 1.$$